# Compare date with min and max value not working

Tags: angularjs, datetime

I trying to compare date to in min value and max value and something going wrong there.

```
        var dueDate = moment().add(10, 'years').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
        var minDate = moment().add(-10, 'years').format('DD-MM-YYYY');

        var checkValidDate = function(date) {
            if (Date.parse(date) > minDate || Date.parse(date) < dueDate) return date;
            return null;
```

and I always getting null

[result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTIN1.png)

Thanks!

Comment: can you cast a Date object on both of them and compare by value? `new Date(minDate).valueOf()`?

Comment: tried to cast both of them. couldn't understand how to use value of in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change date strings to Date Objects, So you need to do

```
new Date(minDate)
```

But Date constructor assumes the minDate to be in format 'MM-DD-YYYY' where as now it is in 'DD-MM-YYYY'.

```js
 var dueDate = moment().add(10, 'years').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
 var minDate = moment().add(-10, 'years').format('MM-DD-YYYY');

        var checkValidDate = function(date) {
               date = moment(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
            if (new Date(date) > new Date(minDate) || new Date(date) < new Date(dueDate)) return date;
            return null;  
         }
```

Or keep every date in moment and just compare

Answer (score 0):

> You should convert the date object to string first using moment() and then changing the format using format();

```
 var checkValidDate = function(date) {
        date = moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');//assuming the parameter date is a Date type object
        if (date > minDate || date < dueDate) return date;
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I go through the code that you posted and found that you are using two different ways to compare the values i.e one is moment js and other is jquery Date.parse function.

```
var dueDate = moment().add(10, 'years').format('DD-MM-YYYY');console.log(dueDate)
var minDate = moment().add(-10, 'years').format('DD-MM-YYYY'); console.log(minDate)
var testDate = moment().add(2, 'years').format('DD-MM-YYYY'); console.log(testDate)
var checkValidDate = function(testDate) {
 if (testDate > minDate || testDate < dueDate){ return testDate} else
     return null;
 };
checkValidDate(testDate);
```

result: "26-04-2020" 
This will return the date in string format, not in the date format. You need to pass the same in this way 
 new Date(04 + '/' + 26 + '/' + 20)
 that will gives you the output: Sun Apr 26 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Thanks